# Edit text of several buttons using a for loop

Tags: android, android-button

I have 16 buttons, whose names are "button1", "button2", and so on.  Is there a way I can iterate through them using a for loop, by somehow appending the number value upon each iteration?  Something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i<17; i++ ){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoni);
```

I know I can simply initialize each button in my onCreate() method, but I was just curious if I could do it in a way similar to my example code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) :

```
for(int i = 1; i<17; i++ ){        
     int buttonId = getResources().getIdentifier("button"+i, "id", getPackageName());
     Button b = (Button)findViewById(buttonId);
     //Your stuff with the button
}
```

Comment: @AleksG Do you have an alternative?

Comment: @Richard there are no alternatives - this is the only way, and it's rather slow.  You may want to rethink your logic if you need to do something like this.  For example, create buttons in the code instead of XML and store them in the array when you're creating them.  Then you'd simply need to loop over your array.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the edit! And yes, at AleksG pointed out, this is slow and it's mentionned in the doc _"Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name."_

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of `Button`'s and use `getIdentifier` method that allows you to get an identifier by its name.

```
final int number = 17;
final Button[] buttons = new Button[number];
final Resources resources = getResources();

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    final String name = "btn" + (i + 1);
    final int id = resources.getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());

    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(id);
}
```

**In case someone is interested how to achive the same result using Java only**

The solution above uses `Android` specific methods (such as `getResources`, `getIdentifier`) and can not be used in usual `Java`, but we can use a `reflection` and write a method that works like a `getIdentifier`:

```
public static int getIdByName(final String name) {
    try {
        final Field field = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
final Button[] buttons = new Button[17];

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(getIdByName("btn" + (i + 1)));
}
```

`NOTE:`

Instead of optimizing this kind of code you should rethink your layout. If you have 17 buttons on the screen, a ListView is probably the better solution. You can access the items via index and handle onClick events just like with the buttons.